# Sphinx autodoc/napoleon doesn't generate docstrings

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

I'm doing a really simple example and can't get it to work. I just have one file, `simulator.py` that I added numpy style docstrings to. It does not import any other libraries. It has an `__init__` and I can import it from a python interpreter. My directory structure is as follows:

```
|__ modules
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ simulator
   |   |__ simulator.py
   |__ docs
       |__ Makefile
       |__ _static
       |__ conf.py
       |__ index.rst
       |__ modules.rst
       |__ _build
       |__ _templates
       |__ simulator.rst
       |__ make.bat
```

I'm using sphinx-build 4.0.2. I pip installed sphinxcontrib-napoleon even though sphinx-ext.napoleon is supposed to be included in later versions of sphinx.

In my conf.py, I have

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

and

```
extensions = [
'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
'sphinx.ext.napoleon'
]
```

To make my `.rst` files I run `sphinx-apidoc -f --ext-autodoc -o . ../simulator` from the `docs` directory. It creates `modules.rst` and `simulator.rst`. I added 'modules' to the toctree in `index.rst`, and 'simulator' is in the toctree that was autobuilt in `modules.rst`.

It creates a heading in each file and a toctree. No docstrings. I read that it just creates the model to build the html from the docstrings, so I ran `make html`. It builds with just the table of contents, nothing from the docstrings. What could be going wrong? I've tried different variations of the `path.insert()` command even though I'm pretty sure what I have is correct. I've tried moving `simulator.py` into the main directory, I've tried adding a bunch of other random crap from examply `conf.py` files I've found from searching other solutions to this issue. None of the solutions have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))`. You're actually adding `modules` to the Python path, so `import simulator` would import `modules/simulator` and not `modules/simulator/simulator` as you would like.
You should rather do:

```
|__ modules
   |__ simulator
   |   |__ __init__.py
   |   |__ simulator.py
   |__ docs
       |__ ...
```

and change your `conf.py` to:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../simulator'))
```

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why it didn't work when I just moved `simulator.py` to the `modules` directory so the structure matched the example I was following? Now that I have a working example I can play around with that myself. The `docs` dir should really be in `simulator` since that will more closely model what I actually want to document.